# mongo db how to join collections

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

How to fetch records as join full outer in mongo db 3.2

inventory collection

```
db.inventory.insert([
{ "_id" : 1, "coin_id" : "12345", description: "product 1"},
{ "_id" : 2, "coin_id" : "12346", description: "product 2"},
])
```

Order Collection

```
db.orders.insert([
{ "_id" : 1, "coin_id" : "12345", "user_id" : 11, "bal" :1000 },
])
```

Here Scenario is like that. i want to fetch reocrd from inventory collection on the basis of coin_id,then matching record from order collection. but if not matched on order  collection , it will be give at least inventory records .

My code -:

```
db.inventory.aggregate([
{
    $lookup:
    {
       from: 'orders',
       localField: 'coin_id',
       foreignField: 'coin_id',
       as: 'coin_details'
    }
},  {$match : {'coin_details.user_id':'11')}}
```

I always want to records from inventory records whenever either user_id will empty or not available 
If any other possibility available please let me know. please guide me how to do it.

Comment: Change or remove `$match` stage. It filters out records without matching order.

Comment: but i want to this comparison. because i want value according to user_id. if it is not exist on collection then it will ok ,but if exist then i want.

Comment: Sure, but your `$match` in current edition says "leave only records where user_id is 11". Without any "if it is not exist". Change the "$match" to meet your requirements.

Comment: thanks ,could you please guide me how it will possible at this stage?

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/ and https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/size/

Comment: @RiyaSinghal you need to unwind `coin_details` then use ` {$match : {'coin_details.user_id':'11')}}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$match` condition should be changed to meet requirements "matching user id, or no matching order" :

```
db.inventory.aggregate([
    { 
        $lookup:
        {
            from: 'orders',
            localField: 'coin_id',
            foreignField: 'coin_id',
            as: 'coin_details'
        }
    },  
    { $match : {$or: [
        {'coin_details.user_id':11}, 
        {'coin_details':{$size:0}}
    ] } }
] )
```

As a side note, user_id is a number in the sample document, so it should be in the query.

Comment: thanks it working ,but can we manage limit for the inventory records  because it is giving all the records of on inventory.

Comment: But it is what you have asked: *I always want to records from inventory records whenever either user_id will empty or not available*. You can amend `$match` with more restrictive condition to get only documents you are interested in, or use https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/limit/ to get "first n" documents that match the condition.

Answer (score 0):

remove the `$match` pipeline, it will return the inventory document with empty array of order if not match found

```
db.inventory.aggregate([
{
    $lookup:
    {
       from: 'orders',
       localField: 'coin_id',
       foreignField: 'coin_id',
       as: 'coin_details'
    }
}
])
```

Comment: but i want to this comparison. because i want value according to user_id. if it is not exist on collection then it will ok ,but if exist then i want

Comment: what you want to do if user_id doesn't exists?

Comment: in that case i always want  to inventory collection records.

Comment: this will show inventory even order or user_id doesn't exits

Comment: can you post sample documents and expected result?